# Creating a single line from output of multiple shell commands

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I try to ssh to multiple hosts (thousands of them), capture some command output and write in a file. But output of all command should be in same line, comma separated, space separated, anything but in same line for each host.

So my commands are like":

```
ssh $host "hostname; uname -r; echo mypassword| sudo -S ipmitool mc info | grep 'Firmware Revision' " > ssh.out
```

But if I use like this, it will write all command output to separate lines. (3 lines per host). But all I want is only one line per host, let's say:

```
myserver,3.2.45-0.6.wd.514,4.3 (comma or any field separator is fine)
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bash [Array variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html).  Append the output of each `ssh` command to the array.  At the end, `echo` all elements of the array.  The result will be all array elements on a single line.  Set [`IFS`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) (the internal field separator) to desired per-host delimiter.  (I used `,`.)  For handling multiple lines of output from multiple commands within the same ssh session, use [`tr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) to replace newlines with a delimiter.  (I used a space.)

### Code

```
sshoutput=()

for host in host01 host02 host03; do
    sshoutput+=($(ssh $host 'echo $(hostname; uname -a; echo mypassword) | tr "\n" " "'))
done

IFS=,; echo "${sshoutput[*]}";
```

### Output

```
host01.domain.com Linux host01.domain.com 2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 20 11:30:02 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux mypassword ,host02.domain.com Linux host02.domain.com 2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 20 11:30:02 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux mypassword ,host03.domain.com Linux host03.domain.com 2.6.32-696.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Apr 20 11:30:02 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux mypassword
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very neat but using `printf` works. `hostname` and `uname -r` are verified to work. I don't know what `ipmitool` outputs so I can't verify it.

```
ssh $host "printf $(hostname),$(uname -r),$(echo mypassword| sudo -S ipmitool mc info | grep 'Firmware Revision')\n" > ssh.out
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the output of `ssh` into a variable and then print it:

```
ssh_output=$(ssh $host "hostname; uname -r; echo mypassword | sudo -S ipmitool mc info | grep 'Firmware Revision' ")
printf '%s\n' "$ssh_output"
```

---

- See this document which explains how shell processes the command output above: [Bash Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)
- Related post: [How to set a variable to the output from a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash)